# Terminology about cooking meat on a rod over a fire

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

If you "**poke**" a beef steak in a "**long metal rod**" and then you hold it by hand on a fire to cook it, this is called what?

It's grilling in BrE and you could say: *I was grilling the steak*. The verb is *to broil* in UK, and according to Cambridge's dictionary it is "*to broil*" in AmE, but I never heard "*I was broiling the steak*"; I don't mean it doesn't exist, just telling you I don't know. What do you say in the scenario above, "I'm **broiling** the steak, and I like to eat it **broiled**"? or use a different verb and expression? And by the way, I'm interested in ***informal speech*** not formal one.

Could you also rewrite **poke** and give the name of "long metal rod" in your everyday AmE language?

Comment: It's *barbeque*

Comment: Yeah, it seems this is the answer I'm looking for; it looks perfect esp. with the poking correction! I only need this in a formal answer not a comment so other native speakers confirm or improve. Thank you.

Comment: @MaulikV - I disagree; one can barbecue without a skewer. Moreover, _barbecue_ means different things to different people; some differentiate between _grilling_ and _barbecuing_ depending on what's being cooked, and how it will be ultimately served.

Comment: You can use `toast` for other things cooked in this way: you can toast bread over a fire, or toast marshmallows over a fire. You wouldn't normally use `toast` for meat though.

Comment: I think if I say *"hot rod grill"* or *hot rod BBQ", everyone would know what I mean. Wait for native speakers to confirm that.

Comment: learner, *broil* is a strange and unfamiliar word in the UK.

Comment: @Tristan I believe so; actually I've never heard it or seen it used by individuals. Though, I find it written on some kitchen appliances (just to get out of the confusion!)

Comment: I’ve always seen *broiling* used to refer to cooking something that is suspended very close to, but under, a heat source.

Comment: KRyan, where is that word used? It is not common in the UK.

Comment: @Tristan "Broiling" is commonly used in the U.S.  Many (most) home ovens sold here have a "bake" setting that uses a top and bottom element to hold the interior at a preset temperature, and a "broil" setting that turns on the top elements full blast.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The metal rod is called a *skewer*. (If it's a bigger rod, designed to hold entire animals and rotate, it's called a *spit*.)

I would say that cooking over an open fire is called *roasting*; cooking over a fire on a metal grate is called *grilling* (or *barbecuing*, although *barbecuing* may imply the use of some kind of marinade or *barbecue sauce*).

Cooking over an open heat source with meat on a continuously rotating spit is called *rotisserie cooking*.

When meat is on a skewer, that can also be called a *kabob*, particularly when meat and vegetables are mixed together on the same skewer.

That all said, there is plenty of room for overlap and confusion. One can *roast* in an oven, or can make *barbecued chicken* in a crock pot. One can also *grill* in a frying pan. (Grilled cheese sandwich, anyone?)

Cooking terms are often chosen to indicate the type of heat source, the direction of the heat source, and the dish being prepared.

As for the scenario you described (open fire, using a skewer, no grill or grate), I'd probably call that *roasting*, although it would be hard to argue for a single, universal "best word" – cooking is simply too diverse for that.

Comment: I found this question a very good one! ;) I find myself wanting to read more. I have never known the differences between meat cooking methods before today, and I think I need to read more. And yes, there is some confusion. However, I found some interesting paragraph on the barbeque article on Wikipedia quoted in the next comment.

Comment: "While there is a vast degree of variation and overlap in terminology and method surrounding this form of cooking, the generally accepted difference between barbecue and grilling is in the cooking time and the type of heat used: grilling is generally done "hot and fast" over direct heat from low-smoke fuels (with the flame contacting the meat itself), while barbecuing is usually done "low and slow" over indirect heat from high-smoke fuels (with the flame not contacting the meat directly)." Source = Wikipedia

Comment: Perhaps you can learn more about the differences in these methods of cooking at [cooking.se].

Comment: Note also that English is very happy to borrow vocabulary from other cultures when the word describes a particular cooking process that English doesn’t have a word for (as seen here with the suggestion of *kebab*, which is borrowed from a word found in Arabic, Turkish, and Persian and means pretty much the same thing in English as it does in those languages). Note that English speakers will borrow words incorrectly though (such as using a foreign word for “cook” to specifically refer to one particular cooking style from that culture, or using the name of a specific dish for a range of things).

Comment: I suggest the verb for this would be to _spitroast_.  (It's often used to imply cooking the whole animal, but that's not as burdened/wrong as using _barbecue_ might be.)

Answer (score 2):

Okay, looking at the comment, I'm not sure whether you want to know the term for the procedure of cooking or the instrument used. Anyway, answering here all probabilities!

The proper word could be *barbeque*.

> [Barbecue (transitive verb)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/barbeque) - *to cook (food) on a barbecue.*

Just down there, the [full definition of barbecue](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/barbeque) as stated in Merriam Webster -

> Barbecue - to roast or broil on a rack or revolving spit over or before a source of heat (as hot coals)

For the style of cooking, it's called as **[Rotisserie](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotisserie)**

For the rod, it's [**Skewer**](http://www.wordwebonline.com/en/SKEWER).

Comment: As for the tool, I'm interested in the one rod sort of thing not the metal frame, that's why I didn't mention or maybe forgot to mention BBQ. I don't know the fine line- if it exists- between barbequing, which I have enjoyed, and "broiling" that steak in the rod if they are different. Are they the same or different?

Comment: The skewer is what use *by hand* to broil but I think when it's broiled slowly *by a machine* it becomes Rotisserie according to the picture in your link.

Comment: I have not read the article only read the picture description. Anyway, according to the chunk I read, it doesn't seem what I am looking for. Rotisserie is for big chunks of meat or entire animals. I have to read more to learn. That rod "skewer" too is called spit in Rotisserie.

Comment: @learner Your question reads what's the term for cooking on fire (it's barbeque/Rotisserie). Then, you said *as per the tool, I'm interested in one rod sort of thing...* it's *skewer*. Rotisserie is **also** for the food over a fire in a fireplace or over a campfire. I wonder what exactly you want!

Comment: In some places in the U.S., _barbecue_ implies more than just grilling over an open fire, but also cooking with a _barbecue sauce_. In other words, some might argue: no sticky marinade, no barbecue – just grilling over an open fire. Also, _rotisserie_ implies the meat is continuously turning as it cooks; you should mention this in your answer.

Comment: Sorry if that made you confused.I think the problem was the title I put. This happens when I try to precisely explain what I want in the body of the post but tend not to put effort to choose the right title. The title is little space, and it seems misleading in my case. So please consider the body is the question itself because it has the *details and context* which is more important that the title which gives me hard time to choose the right little words in the little space. Accept my apology too, please.

Comment: Rotisserie implies the spit is suspended from something as well, I would say. I wouldn't call a piece of meat on a skewer held by a person over a fire "rotisserie".

Comment: @J.R. In quite some places barbecue implies actually _no_ open fire at all, but glowing charcoal or something similar - though gas-operated barbecues that simulate these cooking conditions _do_ use actual flames for heating.

Comment: @oerkelens - And then again, some would lump hot charcoal under the same umbrella as "open fire" (as opposed to, say, an electric oven).

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you do not poke the steak in a rod, but you poke the steak with a rod, or rather, you *skewer* it.

The rod is also called a skewer.

Grilling seems to be the right verb for cooking it this way, though **roasting** is also an option. Roasting does not imply the use of a grill - so it may be better suited for this.

@MaulikV: there is no barbecue mentioned, or anything like it, in the OP's description.
Just putting a stick through a piece of meat and holding it over a fire is not the same as putting meat on a metal grill over glowing charcoal (which is a barbecue).

Comment: There is no grill mentioned either.

Comment: Correct. A skewer is mentioned though. True, grilling does imply the presence of a grill - maybe roasting is better. A barbecue means no open fire or holding skewers with meat over open fire.

Comment: @oerkelens Is OP concerned about food being cooked that way over open fire or in kitchen? It's just *before a source of heat?*

Comment: Good question, I read "hold it by hand on a fire" as "hold it over a fire", which seems to evoke the idea of an open fire. I guess you could read "fire" as "any heat source, be it fire, glowing charcoal or electrical heat".

Comment: I meant open fire made by burning wood outdoors. So it is over fire eh! On a fire is just an L1 interference! I didn't notice that while I'm writing, even after!

Answer (score 2):

I speak AmE, mostly informally; and I have broiled any number of steaks in the past. I like my steak broiled, and I hope to broil many more steaks in the future. I wish I were broiling a steak right now, or that I had finished my cooking and were sitting down to eat my freshly broiled steak.

I usually broil my steaks by laying the steak on a grill over an open fire or under a gas flame or electric heating element.

I could also skewer the meat on a thin (1/8" or so) metal rod 18"-36" in length,  and then hold one end of the skewer in my hand and use the other end to hold the meat over a fire (or other heat source) until it was cooked to my satisfaction. ("Skewer" is both the noun for the metal rod, and the verb for getting the food in place on that rod.)

If I got tired of holding and turning the skewer over the fire, I might wish I had a spit over the fireplace: a metal rod at least 1/4" or so in diameter and a couple of feet long, resting in two forked rods standing vertically on either side of the fire,   with a handle projecting from one end of the spit. Then once I got my steak spitted onto the rod, I could turn my steak over the fire simple by turning the spit handle. (Once on the rod, the meat has been "spitted" there; but I've never heard anybody use "spit" as the verb for doing this in the present tense. I think I would have to place, put, thread or even skewer the meat onto the spit; or impale the meat with the spit; in order to get it spitted and ready to broil.)

If I used a grill, I would call mine a grilled steak, or a broiled one.

If I used a skewer, I would call my steak broiled or roasted.

If I used a spit, I would call it a roasted steak.

I would not call it a barbequed steak unless I had applied a barbeque-type sauce to it during cooking, even though I might have used a barbeque grill to cook my broiled steak. (However, I have only ever lived along the West coast of the US. For serious BBQ and serious BBQers & BBQ terminology, you'll need someone from the southeastern US.)

Comment: This matches my usage exactly (Also West Coast AmE)